# How to remove duplicated Skype entries from Contacts

Tags: windows-10-mobile, contacts, skype

Today, my Windows phone decided that it would be good to have a copy of all Skype contacts in the Contacts app. (Perhaps Skype was updated or something happened, in any case it did also seem to reload all conversations when I opened Skype on the phone this morning.)

Also, all of my other contacts that were linked with the Skype entries, they are now linked to two redundant Skype entries.

How do I clean up this mess?